# Script .batch to rename a computer

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, string-comparison

I need a script to rename a machine with a name that I choose myself, I also need to compare if the machine is already with that name because that same script will be used for more things.

I got to this code, but even if teh name i set is te same as the mchine it runs the IF

```
TITLE PADRONIZACAO
@ECHO off
COLOR 1f
CLS

SET /p name=Inset the machine name: 
IF /I NOT "%name%" == "%computername%"( ECHO The machine will be renamed to %name% 
WMIC ComputerSystem WHERE NAME="%computername%" RENAME "%name%"
ECHO The machine will be restarded
PAUSE
SHUTDOWN -r -f -t 0 
) ELSE ( 
ECHO The machine has already ben renamed 
)

ECHO the instalations will be started
PAUSE
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Surely you need to change ```IF "%name%" == "%computername%" (``` to ```IF /I NOT "%name%" == "%computername%" (```!

Comment: It worked, now IF is running at least, but even if the machine name is the same it is not running the ELSE

Comment: That surprises me, because WMIC.exe does not have an alias named `computersistem`, it should be `ComputerSystem`. So how about you use your actual batch file, and copy exactly what it contains, and paste it into the code box in your question, so that wr can help you with what it really contains.

Comment: Actually, i had written the wrong command. Now i update the code in the question and also the problem that is occurring now